# Error with append and creating dictionary in append. ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I would like to add the `city` to it and then print ouput: `Liverpool, Jonny 33.` I would like to set `city` as primary key.

Before adding city, my code worked fine because i used `name` as primary key, and i got output: Jonny 33 , under it Tiffany 45, under it Margot 21.  But now, adding the `city` key, i have this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Maybe the mistake is that i created the dictionary wrong and messed up the way i added `city` to it, and so it's not being called correctly in the second loop.

How can I also add city (before the name)?

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.connect('abc')
cursor = c.cursor()

x = {}

def Button_func():
   data = c.execute('SELECT city, name1, name2, number FROM MyListTable')

    for r in data.fetchall():   
        if r[0] not in x:
            x[r[0]] = []
        x[r[0]].append([r[1], r[3]])

    for key_city, val_name, val_number in x.items():
        result = sum(val_number) / 2
        print(key_city, val_name, result)


Button_func()
```

Comment: Your code implies that you are going to get multiple names in each city.  Is that correct?  Is the "primary key" of your dictionary going to be the city, or the name?

Comment: @TimRoberts That's right, the code implies that you are going to get multiple names in each city. For example i would like to print: Liverpool, Jonny 33 , under it Paris, Tiffany 45, under it Brighton, Margot 21. Now the primary key of the dictionary is name, but i would like it to be city. I tried to add it, but i get ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Why are you testing `r[0]` but then using `r[1]` when creating the new dictionary entry?

Comment: You can simplify this by using `Collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Please post the code that gets the error, along with the full traceback. Don't post the working code and describe how you changed it.

Comment: @Barmar Right. You are right. Excuse me. I'm new. I've updated the question with the code that throws the error. Can you please help me with an answer? I'd love to read other answers other than kind Tim Roberts' answer. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested loops to loop over the residents of each city.

```
def Button_func():
    data = c.execute('SELECT city, name1, name2, number FROM MyListTable')

    for city, name1, name2, number in data.fetchall():   
        x.setdefault(city, []).append([name1, number])

    for key_city, residents in x.items():
        avg_number = sum(res[1] for res in residents) / len(residents)
        print(f'City: {key_city}\nAvg: {avg_number}')
        for res_name, res_number in residents:
            print(f' Name: {res_name}, Age: {res_number}')
```

Comment: I'm confused for a moment. Your code gives me this error: for key_city, (val_name, val_number) in x.items():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). I would just print these: Liverpool, Jonny 33 and the others below them

Comment: It now prints correctly :) I thank you. But there is no result = sum(val_number) / 2. How and where should I add it? (this calculation is just an example, don't ask yourself the logic)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `val_number` is a number, not a list, so you can't sum it. And why divide by 2?

Comment: you could do `result = val_number / 2` without `sum()`

Comment: I had not gone into detail so as not to dwell on the appeal. Actually I would like to do an arithmetic mean. The sum of my number (the one in the database) / len(number). How can I add it? Thank you

Comment: See Tim Robert's answer for how to do that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show everything.

Comment: Tim's answer, about the mean, throws me an error. Mine worked fine (before adding key city as primary key). I trusted in your kind and brilliant help.

Answer (score 0):

This will print all the names in the format you want:

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.connect('abc')
cursor = c.cursor()

rows = {}

def Button_func():
    data = c.execute('SELECT city, name1, name2, number FROM MyListTable')
    for city,name1,name2,number in data.fetchall():   
        if city not in x:
            x[city] = []
        x[city].append( (name1,number) )

    for key,val in x.items():
        for name,num in val:
            print( f"{key}, {name} {num}" )

Button_func()
```

Your code implies that you are supposed to print the average age of the people from each city.  In that case, you wouldn't want the people's names in there.

```
    for key,val in x.items():
        print( key, sum(k[0] for k in val)//len(val) )
```

Comment: With your code i only get the printing of 3 lines. I get one row for each city key. So 3 rows total

Comment: I would like to get a list of names and numbers for each city key. With your code I only get 2 names for each city, and 3 lines

Comment: See, you didn't give that much detail in your question.  If you want an average, then of course you will get one line per city.  If you want the individual names, that take a bit more.